# Pyinstaller fails on Linux with missing `objcopy`

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

I have simple python code that prints hello (`hello.py`) that I want to make  executable using pyinstaller, to run on Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

def welcome():
    print('Welcome')

welcome()
```

I apply the command `pyinstaller hello.py` and I end up with the following exception:

```
6204 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
6205 INFO: Bootloader /home/nour/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
6206 INFO: checking EXE
6206 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
6206 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
6206 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /home/nour/python/build/hello/hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nour/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  <...>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'objcopy'
```

What I tried already and did not help:

- I changed python3.5 to python3 and python

Any hints?

Comment: Please format your code so people can read it. See the formatting help when [edit]ing.

Comment: What command produced that output?

Comment: If you type `objcopy` to the shell, does it tell you how to install it?

Comment: @Attie the command is  pyinstaller hello.py
when I am on the directory where I have my code

Comment: @MarkPlotnick

[nour@localhost python]$ objcopy
bash: objcopy: command not found
[nour@localhost python]$ cd..
[nour@localhost ~]$ objcopy
bash: objcopy: command not found
[nour@localhost ~]$ 

I don't think so

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? Just copying your `hello.py` to a host with Python should allow you to run it there. Finding a Linux host without Python these days is exotic. On the other hand, the way to install Python depends on your distro and hardware architecture.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/requirements.html hints that you might want to install `binutils` for your distro in order to install `objcopy`.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for the answer
I am doing this because I am required to have standaone python code , the hello file is to make it easy to learn only 
----------------------
I am unable to install 

[root@localhost nour]# pip3 install objcopy
Collecting objcopy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement objcopy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for objcopy
[root@localhost nour]# pip3 install binutils
Collecting binutils
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement binutils (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for binutils

Comment: `objcopy` is not Python, you don't use `pip` to install it but something like `apt-get` or `yum` or `apk` or whatever works on your particular Linux distro.  Try `apt-get install binutils` if you are on a Debian-based platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared without changing anything after a week or so